# Blender Crashes Requesting more GPU Memory

Tags: shaders, gpu

I was working on the nodes withing the shader editor and suddenly this pop up appeared asking for more GPU memory.

The current configuration of my system is

16 gb ram

nvidia quadro k2000 2gb

It happended when I was on Evee

**Do I need to upgrade my Graphic card to a 4 gb ?**

[image]

Any Help will be Appreciated

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3553/~/opengl-request-for-more-gpu-memory-than-is-available-meaning

Answer (score 1):

You're using a very old graphics card compared to the generations of GPUs being made nowadays. Blender recently increased their system requirements due to all the new features being added. So yeah, its preferable if you get a 4GB or better GPU.

https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Edit: A GPU capable of running Blender 2.8 is fairly cheap. You can easily get a Nvidia GTX 1050Ti for somewhere around $140, and it'll be suitable for another 1-2 years before needing a slightly better model to compete with Blender's updates.